# Icefaces vs Richfaces vs Primefaces for web and mobile applications

Tags: mobile, frameworks, richfaces, primefaces, icefaces

I would like to know what is the best technology to use when it comes to application development that works well for both web and mobile? The world is moving towards HTML 5 and CSS 3 and Icefaces , Richfaces and Primefaces all have HTML 5 support. I have to choose the one which would be better for existing applications to be converted as well as new application development.

I did my part of the research and found out that either Richfaces or Primefaces would be better but most of my applications were developed using IceFaces.

Please throw in your suggestions to choose the best technology for web and mobile. Thanks.

Comment: Just a note, IceFaces 3 is a fork of PrimeFaces. http://www.icesoft.org/projects/ICEfaces/ace-primefaces-faq.jsf#why-did-icesoft-fork-primefaces.

Answer (score 0):

You may not be aware that [ICEmobile-Faces 1.0](http://www.icesoft.org/projects/ICEmobile/overview.jsf) has just been released.  It is based on the ICEfaces framework, providing all the benefits of ICEfaces, but includes a suite of light-weight mobile components.  It allows you to write mobile applications in JSF that adapt automatically to the client device, so you can build one application that spans Android, iPhone and Blackberry devices.  Additionally, ICEmobile offers device containers that provide device-specific integration to native features like the camera.  Our focus going forward is to develop capabilities that easy development of web apps that span desktop and mobile environments.